# iOS Crash saying : [NSURLSessionDataTask state]: unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have screen with searchbar, when i leave this screen, i am just cancelling the ongoing running urlSessionDataTask. Here, is my code, by which i am using:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if self.lastURLSessionDataTask != nil, self.lastURLSessionDataTask!.state == .running{
       self.lastURLSessionDataTask!.cancel();
       self.lastURLSessionDataTask = nil;
    }

    super.viewWillDisappear(animated);
}
```

As you can see in code, i am first checking if my `lastURLSessionDataTask` variable is not nil, then checking its state, if running then cancelling that task.

Now the issue is, it gives crash with detail as : `[NSURLSessionDataTask state]: unrecognised selector sent to instance`.

Also to note: It is not giving crash each and every time, this get appeared randomly at any time. I am not sure, what i am doing wrong. Can anyone have any idea? Does anyone faced this earlier?

Comment: why you're using force casting lastURLSessionDataTask? use a guard statement instead of do it by if let lastSession =  self.lastURLSessionDataTask, lastSession.state == running{}

Answer (score 0):

Because lastURLSessionDataTask is an optional type of `URLSessionTask`, Instead of Force Casting you should either use `guard` statement

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    guard let task = lastURLSessionDataTask, task.state == .running else { super.viewWillDisappear(animated); return }
    task.cancel()
    task = nil
}
```

Or Check the value by

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let task = lastURLSessionDataTask, task.state == .running {
        task.cancel()
        task = nil
    }
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the force cast as the first check is for `nil` and due to short-circuit evaluation the rest of the expression will be skipped if `lastURLSessionDataTask` is `nil`.

Comment: Correct, It was a suggestion not to use force casting that was the only thing I find wrong in this code. Did you find anything that makes the crash happen @vadian

Comment: No, I didn't. `NSURLSessionDataTask` does have a `state` property.  Basically the code is supposed to work.

Comment: maybe `if let task = lastURLSessionDataTask as? URLSessionTask` will help? i don't know.

Comment: Exactly, i feel the same, it must work, but why it is making crash. Also, it is not reproducible, it randomly appears.

Comment: @dreamBegin, As `lastURLSessionDataTask` is already of type `URLSessionDataTask?`(which is subclass of `URLSessionTask`), so i think this is not making any sense.

Comment: if you have declared  lastURLSessionDataTask as  URLSessionDataTask then it should work.

Comment: Yes, thats why i posted this question, i already searched enough via google for such weird behaviour, but not getting any proper solution.